# How to know the element is a child of a parent

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="ulel">
  <li id="liel">
     <a id="ael"></a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

How I can know that if `#ael` anchor exists inside `#ulel` in jquery?

Comment: Do you want to select only the ael inside the ulel?

Comment: Directly inside or anywhere inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find whether a child exists in parent :

```
if ($('#ulel').find('#ael').length > 0) {
     //do something
}
```

or the other way around, if you want to check whether a child has a parent :

```
if ($('#ael').parents('#ulel').length > 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
if ( $('#ael', '#ulel').length ) {
  // #ael exists in #ulel
}
```

Comment: +1 for least possible number of characters to write this condition (not counting spaces)

Comment: @popnoodles: Could be shorter but less readable: `if ( $('#ael', '#ulel')[0] ) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `.find(...)` jQuery function. You can find more about in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

If you want to select the id "ael" inside of "ulel", you can do this:

```
myAel = $("#ulel").find("#ael");
// Verify if myAel isn't null
if(myAel) {
  alert("My id exists. :)");
}
```

Comment: if using `find`, you don't need `length` so `if(myAel)` would do the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
if ($("#ael").parents('#ulel').length) {
    alert('Has parent "ulel"');
}
```

See [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)  jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

If identify children in any level ,we can use `jquery find()` method

Refference http://api.jquery.com/find/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="ulel">
  <li id="liel">
     <a id="ael"> tst</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
 if( $('#ulel').find('#ael')) {
  $('#ael').css('color','green');
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your starting point is the child, then:

```
if ($("#ael").closest("#ulel")[0]) {
    // Yes, it's in there
}
```

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) finds the first element matching the selector in the element's hierarchy, starting with the one you call it on, then looking at its parent, then its parent's parent, etc.

The `[0]` check at the end is to see if the resulting jQuery set is empty. If it is, there will be no element at `[0]` and so the condition is falsey. If there is, then `[0]` will be the first element, and the condition is truthy. You could also check `.length`:

```
if ($("#ael").closest("#ulel").length) {
    // Yes, it's in there
}
```

or even

```
if ($("#ael").closest("#ulel").length > 0) {
    // Yes, it's in there
}
```